# Python filter massive iterator with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

Here is my code before using multiprocessing. It is a task to get the number of items in a massive iterator which satisfy specified conditions:

```
from itertools import permutations

def f(input_):
    if 'AB' in ''.join(input_):
        return True
    else：
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterator = permutations(['A', 'B',...])
    count = 0
    for item in iterator:  # it is an itertools.permutations object, with str inside
        if f(item):
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

But the iterator is too massive that I need to do multiprocessing or multithread(not sure which is better) to speed the process up.

I have referred to many online references about multi task in Python, and I have tried a few ways. Unfortunately, I still cannot find a solution, since each method I tried is having some problems.
For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(input_):
    if 'AB' in ''.join(input_):
        return True
    else：
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.imap_unordered(f, iterator)
    print(sum(result))
```

In this example, the problem is that this code runs even slower than my original one. I have also tried using pool.map(), but it is also slower than before and it uses up all of my ram.

How should I do to make this filtering task as fast as possible using all my CPU's ability? Multiprocessing and multithreading really confuse me. :(

Comment: It's impossible to say what how to handle this without knowing what the iterator does. Multithreading/processing has its own overhead, and if the iterator does disk I/O, paralellization will not be useful.

Comment: I'd suggest removing unnecessary overhead from the original code by condensing it to `count = sum(map(f, iterator))`. Won't change big-O, but would remove some unnecessary overhead (also, as a microoptimization, `sum`'s fast path will work better if `f` returns `1`/`0` instead of `True`/`False`). That said, any real savings will depend on knowing how `f` is implemented.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The type of the iterator is `itertools.permutations`. Which is permutations of string. Such as permutation of `['A', 'B', 'C']`, and the checking condition is like `if 'AB' in ''.join(input_)`.

Comment: If I understand your description, this is a problem that can very clearly be solved in O(1) time.

Comment: Sorry for providing insufficient information, I have updated the question now.

Comment: @HuiGordon `itertools.permutations` is going to be pretty fast on its own, and if `f` is also fast, then the overhead of sending the task to a child for each iteration is going to exceed the possible gains from parallel processing. I would instead see if I could speed up the single threaded solution with something like `numba`. In my experience, it is very fast for repeating small, simple bits of code at very high frequency. In general `multiprocessing` is good for when you have a long-running (think 100's of ms) cpu-intensive task you have to do many times over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing has a huge overhead compared to `itertools.permutations`. At the same time, pretty much any problem with permutations can be solved using simple factorials.

Your "huge" iterator can be written as

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...]
pattern = ('A', 'B')
sum(pattern in x for x in permutations(data))
```

That being said, there are `factorial(len(data))` possible total permutations. If `data` has no repeats, then there are `factorial(len(data) - len(pattern))` possible arrangements of items besides those in `pattern`, and `len(data) - len(pattern) + 1` places where `pattern` can live.

As of python 3.8, you can do

```
from math import prod

count = prod(range(2, len(data) - len(pattern) + 2))
```

For prior versions, you would have to do

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

count = reduce(mul, range(2, len(data) - len(pattern) + 2), 1)
```

For cases where `data` has repeats that are present in `pattern`, you can do a google search for something like "how many permutations will contain a particular sequence" to help you figure out the analytical formula.

Comment: I see! I used to think parallelisation is always the best way to speed up repeating tasks. So, for this kind of problems(doing membership operators repeatedly), multi-core cpu cannot bring any benefits?

Comment: The reason I use the method of exhaustion is because to verify the analytical formula of some complicated permutations. Although the verifying way is not that efficiency, I want to use the performance of my computer as much as possible to get a shortest time.

Comment: @HuiGordon. Is mathematical proof inferior to sifting through prohibitive masses of data?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean this. Just trying some other ways beside mathematics proof, since enumerating is more straight forward. If using single thread is already fastest for this kind of repeating jobs, I will take it. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to go fast, don't use python. Permutation is easy to implement in say C. And it's easy to split the outer loop into chunks for multithreading or multiprocessing.